# model post back with html attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue with getting the value back in my ViewModel after a postback using a JQuery datepicker. The post back has the correct date with the form group StartDate that does not have a new htmlAttribute attached to the EditorFor. The StopDate does not post back the selected date due to the htmlAttribute. I would prefer not to use a hidden field to send back the data since I know this should work. Anybody have any suggestions?

```
    <div class="form-group" id="StartDate">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reportTimeEntries[0].StartDate, "","StartDate" )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>
    </div>

            <div class="form-group" id="StopDate">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StopDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reportTimeEntries[0].StopDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StopDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
    $('#StartDate .date').datepicker({
        'format': 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        'autoclose': true
    });

    $('#StopDate .date').datepicker({
        'format': 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        'autoclose': true
    });
```

**UPDATE**

So it seems that this has worked by adding this to my ViewModel. The 'Nullable' section seems to allow the date to be posted back.

**ViewModel**

```html
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[Display(Name = "Stop Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> StopDate { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group" id="StopDate">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StopDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reportTimeEntries[0].StopDate, "","StopDate",new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StopDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: EditorFor generates a name, why are you adding a second one?

Comment: Without having the name, my jquery was not populating the datepicker.
 <script>
        $('#Duration .time').timepicker({
            'showDuration': true,
            'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
        });
        
        //$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        //    'format': 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        //    'autoclose': true
        //});
        $('#StartDate .date').datepicker({
            'format': 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'autoclose': true
        });

        $('#StopDate .date').datepicker({
            'format': 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'autoclose': true
        });

Comment: #StartDate/#StopDate is a jquery id selector.  you could remove the #... and just use .date to attach the datepicker to all instances that have class .date.

Comment: Ok. I have removed the second naming convention and the datepicker is still working. Thanks for the suggestion. The post back is still only sending the StartDate since the StopDate has a new htmlAttribute

Comment: The StopDate section of your code is quite confusing.  EditorFor should create an html element inferred from your model.  Then you add another name attribute (which isn't supported). so you should have 1 html element with 2 names and then you add a hidden element with the name StopDate.

Comment: OK I have updated my StopDate section to maybe make it a bit clearer. I have tried to reuse the automatic code in which VS auto-made for me when creating the edit page. I only had the Hidden element for testing to get this to work.

Comment: You view code is not making sense. You are binding to the `StopDate` of an item in a collection property named `reportTimeEntries` but then you `LabelFor()` and `ValidationFor()` are for completely different properties

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand that part is confusing but I would not think that this would effect the postback. After updating those and setting the DataType in the viewmodel this seems to have worked. Thanks for all your help!